# How to deal with special characters in linux passwords

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords

I am running the following command:

`echo 'my!#%^password' | sudo -S bash -c 'useradd -m -s /usr/sbin/nologin -p $(echo my!#%^password | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) george'`

The issue I am having is the special characters. Some break the command, like !@& which seem to be the issue.  Is there a way to run the same command to allow any special characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can "escape" those special characters by using backslash. This character: \

Those characters that are breaking the command need to be preceded by a backslash. Otherwise they are interpreted as Regular Expression characters.

e.g.

```
echo my!#%^password
becomes
echo my\!\#\%\^password
```

I might have missed some but the CLI output should tell you if you've missed them.

Edit: apparently the user interface for stack overflow interprets those backslash characters and removes them. I've surrounded the example in code format.